# Can we automate creation of site on sites.google.com with api?

Tags: api, google-sites

I was wondering if we can create new sites, add new or edit existing pages on a site on sites.google.com with some google api?

I was trying to find some api but unable to find , I found one but it said it is discontinued now

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to have a Corporate account, not a Consumer account and use 'Classic Sites'.  'New Sites' doesn't have all the API capability.  There is no date for Classic Sites being taken down, but you should have plenty of warning when they do finalise this.  Here is the [developer site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#createSite(String,String,String,String)) info.